# loop through 3 lists to Get substrings from elements of a list by using the start and end point from the other 2 lists

Tags: python

I have 3 different lists. Using the corresponding start point and end point from 2 lists I want to make a new list that has the substring from the 1st list.

```
for i in string_list:
    for x in Start_Point_list:
        for y in End_Point_list:
            m= string_list[(i for i in Start_Point_list): (y for y in End_Point_list)]
```

I want to get a list of [m]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make sure it includes sample input data and the corresponding desired output/result.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
m = [string_list[s:e] for s,e in zip(Start_Point_list, End_Point_list)]
```

`zip()` returns an iterator of the corresponding elements in its arguments.  That is, `zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1, 0])` would yield `(1, 3)`, `(2, 2)`, `(3, 1)`, and `(4, 0)`

Comment: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @Brad: It looks like `Start_Point_list` and `End_Point_list` are not composed of integers.  What are they?

Comment: I created those lists as results of sql queries.
if row:
 Start_Point_list2.append(row) 
 Start_Point_list = map(int, Start_Point_list2)

Comment: @Brad: If you print `Start_Point_list` and `End_Point_list`, what do you get?

Comment: @zondo be aware of the vampires. Just saying.

Comment: I get [0,0,0,0] and [11,14,15,12] respectively.

Comment: Oh...its not giving me the substring, rather it makes a list of the same elements of string_list in a nested manner. I don't have a clue.

Comment: I have 4 elements in string_list......hence I am expecting a list containing the substring of those 4 elements.

Comment: In that case, I think you want `m = [string_list[i][s:e] for i, (s,e) in enumerate(zip(Start_Point_list, End_Point_list))]`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The previous answer should I keep it in the nested for loop or outside it?

Comment: It should stand alone.

Comment: It is not iterating while making the substring. It does the substring with the 1st element of the End_Point_list. Please Help

Comment: What is `string_list`?  I'd like to do some testing on my own.

Comment: Thanks @ zondo, the 2nd one worked like a charm.
m = [string_list[i][s:e] for i, (s,e) in enumerate(zip(Start_Point_list, End_Point_list))]